# using source command with dialog

Tags: bash, dialog

Im trying to source a large script with many functions in it that take some time.
I would like to present a dialog "sourcing please wait..." in the mean time.
once done sourcing i want to use my functions.
but using the dialog seems to cancel the souring.
the sourcing does processed with the dialog but the function does not run.

file: main.script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

long task...

function PrintDate(){
date
}
```

file: job1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source main.script.sh | dialog --progressbox "sourcing please wait..." 20 80
PrintDate
```

command prompt:

```
bash job1.sh
```

output i get

```
PrintDate: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nit picks:

1. Your “shebangs” are wrong — they should begin `#!`.
2. You don’t actually need a “shebang” in a file
   that is meant to be sourced. 
   You might want to leave it off so it’s clear that the file
   is meant to be sourced and not run as an ordinary script. 
   (Specifically,
   you should probably start it with a comment that says something like
   `# This file is meant to be sourced and not run as an ordinary script.`)
3. Strictly speaking, you don’t need a “shebang” in a file
   that is meant to be run by `bash scriptname`,
   although it doesn’t hurt.
4. Of course you’re getting `PrintDate: command not found`. 
   Your `main.script.sh` file isn’t defining `PrintDate`;
   it’s defining `PritnDate`.

But the real answer to your question is:

5. The whole point of `source`
   is that the sourced script gets read and interpreted
   in the current main shell process,
   but when you make it part of a pipeline,
   you force it to run in a child process.
6. The trick is to create a pipe without creating a pipeline. 
   The trick to doing this is using *process substitution*
   (a bash extension to *command substitution*). 
   This command:

   ```
   source main.script.sh > >(dialog --progressbox "sourcing please wait..." 20 80)
   ```

   will create a child process to run the `dialog` program,
   and create a pipe from the main shell process to that child process,
   but then it makes that pipe look like an ordinary file,
   and it sends the output from the `source` command to the pipe
   while making it look like an ordinary redirection of the standard output. 
   Therefore, the `source` runs in the main shell process
   (which, in this case, is the `bash` process
   that’s running the `job1.sh` script),
   and so your functions are defined in the `job1.sh` script.

Comment: ive corrected according to your remarks. its was just a typo from my side and thanks that works for me!